# Swift returns nil from NSNotification() instantiation that should never return nil

Tags: ios, swift

This is occuring in Swift 1.1, in the following code "theNotification" is occasionally returned as nil, which is crashing NSNotificationCenter.postNotification(). I can't figure out why, as it's very infrequent, might be because the code is in an iOS8 keyboard extension, but I don't know of any reasons why that would matter.

```
class func sendNotificationValue(name : String, value: Int) {
    let notificationQ = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let userDict = ["value": value]
    let theNotification = NSNotification(name: name, object: nil, userInfo: userDict)
    notificationQ.postNotification(theNotification)
}
```

But my other problem is because theNotification isn't an optional, I can't check it for nil, I get "NSObject does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible", so I can't defensively program to prevent the crash.

Obviously the best solution is to figure out why it's returning nil in the first place, but I'm trying to at least not crash in this scenario. Any suggestions for why it would return nil, or how I can check theNotification for nil here?

Resolution:

The worst bugs make you feel silly when you solve them and I feel extra silly about this one. The problem was never with nil NSNotification allocations, LLDB was lying to me about that as it is wont to do in Swift occasionally. Looking at the notification with PO revealed it was being allocated fine.

My real problem turns out to be that extensions and their controllers can be unloaded from memory occasionally. I was not removing my notification handlers when it was, so when it reloaded NSNotificationCenter attempted to deliver notifications to the unloaded observers, so crash. Something to remember about using NSNotifications in controllers/objects that can be unloaded, remove those observers when they are.

Comment: Oh, and the inputs are always valid. Name is always a constant String, and it really doesn't matter what value is, but it's always a small integer value.

Comment: Ok, adding as NSNotification? to the allocation line allows me to compile a nil check at least, not sure why i forgot that, but is there any reason the allocation should fail?

Comment: From what I read in the docs, `nil` is not really a valid object for `NSNotification`. You could also try using `[NSNotification postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:))

Comment: I'm going to guess that the crashes are only in a Release build. Am I guessing right?

Comment: No it's crashing in a debug build. Now let userDict = ["value: value] is returning nil, but not sure why it's forcing NSNotifcation() to fail. I'm debugging it now, but it seems most likely that I have a wild pointer problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply type `theNotification` as an Optional when you create it:

```
let theNotification: NSNotification? = 
    NSNotification(name: name, object: nil, userInfo: userDict)
```

Now it is legal to compare `theNotification` with `nil`.

Comment: ...and [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) with #IUO in the title so they can either fix the nullability annotation on the NSNotification initializer or fix the initializer to never return nil as it promises.

Comment: This makes it legal to compare but that doesn't help. If an Objective-C function is declared as nonnull but returns nil, then it is broken, and your Swift code is in deep trouble.

Comment: @gnasher729 Luckily few if any places in the Cocoa API make this mistake nowadays. There used to be quite a few. If you find one, file a bug!